# AWS Route 53 integration with Cloudfront error (403)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I deployed a react app to AWS recently after following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/deploy-a-react-app-to-s3-and-cloudfront-with-aws-mobile-hub/), everything is working fine except when I wanted to integrate a custom domain that I bought recently using AWS Route 53, I get an error (403).

For the integration of Route 53 with CloudFront I followed these steps in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html) as they are, I know that my problem is related to some sort of permission authority, but I don't know where exactly I did something wrong.

[image: Page error 403]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solved, my problem was related to unassigned **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** for the ***CloudFront*** Distribution.

Comment: Absolutely correct. However, for readers too inpatient to finish the whole sentence in the answer: this setting is in CloudFront, not Route 53!

Comment: Great, thanks, this pointed me in the right direction! When using serverless with AWS Amplify, go to 'AWS Amplify > Domain Management' and add your domain there. The SSL and DNS propagation will be handled automatically once the domain has been added, so no need to get certs anywhere else

Comment: this also includes the domain itself (example.com). I did not initially have it at first, but after I added it to the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs), it worked!

Comment: @openwonk your comment is actually 50% of the answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Adding additional information regarding the two answers above.

As described in [How do I resolve the error "The request could not be satisfied. Bad Request" from Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cloudfront-bad-request-error/)
:

> This error message "The request could not be satisfied. Bad Request."
>   is from the client and the error can occur due to one of the following
>   reasons:
>
> 1) The request is initiated over HTTP, but the CloudFront distribution
>   is configured to allow only HTTPS requests.
>
> 2) The requested alternate domain name (CNAME) isn't associated with
>   the CloudFront distribution.

**Solution for #1**:
Open the Amazon CloudFront console -> Select the relevant distribution ->
Go Behaviors view -> Choose the behavior that matches the request and Edit ->
Then select in the Viewer Protocol Policy between the options of: `HTTP and HTTPS` or `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`.

**Solution for #2**:
Since [this release](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/)  when you add an alternate domain name to a distribution, you must also attach a SSL/TLS certificate to that distribution that covers the alternate domain name.

So, first of all make sure that you do the following before you update your distribution to add an alternate domain name:

A) Register the domain name with   domain provider (GoDadday, CloudFlare, Route 53 etc').

B) Add a certificate from an authorized certificate authority (for example - [Let's Encrypt](https://medium.com/@cubxi/add-wildcard-lets-encrypt-certifications-with-namecheap-6a466df0886f)) to CloudFront that covers the domain name you plan to use with the distribution, to validate that you are authorized to use the domain.
(Read more in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)).

And only then: 
 
Open Amazon CloudFront console -> General view -> Edit -> Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) -> enter the CNAME that you want to associate with the CloudFront distribution (for example `www` or `home`).

Comment: you may bill my company for the hours you saved me!

Comment: "And only then" - key bit for me! I did that bit first, then R53. Once I re-opened the CF distro and saved it again, it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying http instead of https.

If you have enabled http, then it means the destination method or path cannot be reached.

Comment: what is the proposed solution exactly?

Comment: It is not a magic, there are lot of parameters involved. You need to share all the details of your settings before anyone can propose a solution. This is one of those to start with.